# I was sent an NFT, to ETH/Polygon address, and cannot view it, though it shows (on creators' opensea) as owned my me

Tags: nft, polygon, opensea

After buying some nft's from a creator on opensea (using Polygon on ETH), they sent me one for free. They asked me for my polygon address, and assuming this meant the poly/eth address that is ubiquitous on my metamask, I sent it, and he sent the nft.

Today I checked and did not see it in my collection inventory; went to the creator's page and clicked on the nft in question, and it does show as sent to me / and owned by me. Thus far I've contacted the sender/creator to let them know, and have yet to get any feedback.
I've also cleared out my browser cache and reset/disconnected/reconnected my metamask wallet, and still trying to solve this.

My question is what could have possibly happened or gone wrong, and how to rectify this situation?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Polygon and Ethereum are not necessarily "Ubiquitous" You may need to switch the network from Ethereum main-net to the polygon main-net for your NFT to show up properly.

You can switch the network provider within MetaMask by clicking on the Network tab which will be at the top of the metamask tab when you click on it.

if you have already added the information to connect to the Polygon mainnet, then it should be as simple as switching from the Ethereum network to Polygon's network.

If you do not already have the network added then you would need to click on add network, where you will need to look up the following information to add Polygon network.

RPC URL
Chain ID

The block explorer is also pretty important, but there are more than one to choose from and is optional.

in short, you have to view the assets on the polygon network not the Ethereum network.